# Run portable Qt app executable from batch file

Tags: windows, qt, batch-file

Windows shortcuts have absolute paths that un-reference when moving files to other drives. Instead of a shortcut, I'd like the user to click on a file that's separated from all the Qt dll files in a subdirectory.

I've created a batch file located 1 directory above the executable with a relative path  to run the file.

```
release
     + db
     + plugins
         + platforms
         + iconengines
         + imageformats
     - Qt5Core.dll
     - program.exe
     - etc....
program.bat

//paths set in main()
QCoreApplication::AddLibraryPath("plugins");
```

I found the following code is from [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/28115/portable-shortcuts-on-windows):

```
@start "" "\release\program.exe"
```

But when run, error message "windows cannot find.." is displayed

I've also tried

```
@start "" "release\program.exe"

@start "" "%CD%\release\program.exe"

@start "" "%~dp0\release\program.exe"
```

But I get an error about Qt not finding the "windows" platform plugin, which seems to indicate there's something wrong with the paths.

Why does the program run properly with a windows shortcut and fail with the batch file?

Comment: Does you program run when not run from QtCreator?

Comment: And do you have in path where is your program this file: release/platforms/qwindows.dll?

Comment: I am asking because shortcut possibly uses your environment settings where are paths for Qt, so it finds all dlls needed, whether batch file can have "clean environment" and that's why your program does complain about missing plugin. Try to run program in clean environment, meybe it will fail to run also and problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created program.bat in parent folder of my program with your content and **it works**.

It was tested on machine where is no Qt installed. OS is Windows 7

This is example application structure

```
bin
     + platforms
     + iconengines
     + imageformats
     - Qt5Core.dll
     - program.exe
     - etc....
program.bat
```

program.bat contains:

```
@start "" "bin\program.exe"
```

**So make sure your application is well deployed.**

I use this in my pro file to make sure every release is deployed correctly:

```
# Deployment
CONFIG (release, release|debug) {
win32 {
        QMAKE_POST_LINK = windeployqt $${DESTDIR}/$${TARGET}.exe --no-translations
        # Not necessary when path to VC libraries is correctly set
        externalLibs.files += somepath/_windeploy_/msvcr120.dll
        externalLibs.files += somepath/_windeploy_/msvcp120.dll
        externalLibs.path = $$DESTDIR
        # need to add additional build step (make): install
        INSTALLS += externalLibs
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited my question a little. Can the deployment code be added as it is?

Comment: You should path to your program. I uses DESTDIR variable, so It works on all my win projects.
try to add this: message($${DESTDIR}/$${TARGET}.exe)
If it points to you executable its ok. If not modify Or try to modify path for windeploy
Or simply runs windeployqt program.exe in command line in release folder.